# Apply style to a dataframe with nested if else statement with lambda

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to highlight some rows from a dataframe table by applying lambda to nested if else statements. I followed the syntax but still got a syntax error. Not sure where is the mistake.

example data

```
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c']*2, 'col2': list(range(0, 6))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

highlight the table

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: pink' if (x.name == 5) 
                          else ('background: blue' if (x.name == 1 else '')) 
                          for i in x], axis=1)
```

The ideal output is index 1 and 5 will be highlighted with blue and pink respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-color` instead `background` and move `)` after last `else` after `x.name == 1`:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: pink' if (x.name == 5) 
                          else ('background-color: blue' if (x.name == 1) else '') 
                          for i in x], axis=1)
                                                                       ^^^
```